# unrecognized namespace 'umbraco'

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

Building an Umbraco 6.1.5 MVC site in the .net 4.5 framework using VS2012. When trying to use a couple of common packages, specifically Cultiv Contact Form and the Google Maps datatype I get a green squiggly underline under the word "umbraco" in the following instance:-

```
<umbraco:Macro FileLocation="~/macroScripts/CultivContactForm.cshtml" MailFrom="website@abc.com.com" runat="server" />
```

The error shown if I mouse over "umbraco" is "unrecognized namespace 'umbraco'".

The top of the file has:-

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@using umbraco;
```

I cannot understand why the "@using umbraco" doesn't fix the problem.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because - and it looks like that - ah - sorry to say but razor pages have a different syntax than old asp.net user controls.

It looks to me like you think you can magically use a user control in a razor page. Bad news - no.

Comment: No I don't think that. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: TomTom is correct: <umbraco:Macro /> is a WebForms control and simply cannot be used in a Razor page. Sorry I have no Umbraco experience and can't offer you a solution, but you'll have to search for how to use Macro with the Razor view-engine, OR switch to using a WebForms page rather than a Razor page.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer without the sarcasm. I can now pursue a possible solution.